# How to get json file local and repeat data?

Tags: json, angular

I am new in angular5 and I am trying to load json file and repeat it but I can't repeat data

( i can get and show data form jason file but can't repeat data )

> in src/assets/data.json

```
{ "status": "S","messeage": "error","Card":[
{
  "ID": "01",
  "Price": "30,000",
  "Color": "Black"
},
{
  "ID": "02",
  "Price": "32,000",
  "Color": "Red"
}]}
```

> in src/app/app.component.ts

```
data;
      constructor(private http:Http) {
            this.http.get('../assets/data.json')
            .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());

      }
```

> in src/app/app.component.html

```
{{data?.Card[0].Color}} // => black

{{data?.Card[0].Price}} // => 30,000
```

But I need to know how to repeat it.

Sorry for my english

Thank you for help

---

Edit

last 2 answer it work
but it have error in console

how to fix it ?
thank you so much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd2T8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you get your json  .

You can repeat it like this

In js code .

```
for(i=0;i<data.Card.length;i++){
console.log(data.card[i].Color);
}
```

In angular5 html template

```
 <li *ngFor="let card of data.Card"> 
    {{ card.Color}}
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngFor directive into template to repeate it.

example `<div *ngFor="let obj of data.Card">
           <div>{{obj.Color}}</div>
           <div>{{obj.Price}}</div>
         </div>`